# Voice Recognition Android Increase accuracy to particular word

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, voice

Senario is like i have an order booking app and has multiple item.

What i Want if user says add 6 items in to cart then get the user voice and pick the particular item added into the cart.

I Uses lib
Google speech to text but accuracy is not good because we have accent issues

also uses
https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech2.0

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/#building-and-running-from-android-studio

but not achieving any thing can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: i also used this https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech2.0